# Codeigniter: form_open gave invalid function URL

Tags: forms, codeigniter

I used this function to start a form:
`echo form_open('email/send');`
and after viewing the source I found that form_open returned duplicated index.php :

`<form action="http://localhost/ci/index.php/index.php/email/send"`
Note:
I tried keeping only this line of code in the page, but still gave me the same result

Edit1:

Base url : `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/index.php/';`

Comment: What do you have set for your base url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is your `index_page` configuration item set to?  If your `base_url` and `index_page` configuration items both include `"index.php"` then I imagine `form_open()` would duplicate it.

Change your `application/config/config.php` to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';

//...

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```